# Sql - Not connecting to local database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm working with two databases. From 1st database in the server I'm taking all the tables and inserting in local machine in one empty database using a stored procedure.

This is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[ImportScriptAndData]

@Branch int,
@MainServer varchar(20),
@LocalServer varchar(20),
@LocalDBName varchar(20),
@AuditType int

AS Begin

set nocount on;


-- Delete the master tables

-- dbo.AuditArea
print ('delete from ['+ @LocalServer +'].['+ @LocalDBName +'].[dbo].AuditArea')
exec  ('delete from ['+ @LocalServer +'].['+ @LocalDBName +'].[dbo].AuditArea')

-- Insert data into master tables

-- dbo.AuditArea
print ('insert into ['+ @LocalServer +'].[HDFCAudit].dbo.AuditArea
select * from ['+ @MainServer +'].[HDFCAudit].dbo.AuditArea')
exec ('insert into ['+ @LocalServer +'].['+ @LocalDBName +'].dbo.AuditArea
select * from ['+ @MainServer +'].['+ @LocalDBName +'].dbo.AuditArea')

End
```

This stored procedure is on server database.

I'm connecting two computers on lan. One is server and other is client

On client application I have a button that can be clicked when I want to bring all the tables from server database to local empty database.

My click button code is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(newConn);  //string newConn = "Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=Audit;uid=sa;pwd=admin@123";
            con.Open();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstringLOCAL); //string connectionstringLOCAL = "Data Source=Clientname;Initial Catalog=Audit;uid=sa;pwd=admin@123";
            conn.Open();
            BranchCode = Convert.ToInt32(cboBranch.SelectedValue.ToString());
            MainServer = "Servername";
            LocalServer = "ClientName"; //express
            LocalDatabase = "Audit";
            AuditType = 1;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.ImportScriptAndData", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Branch", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = BranchCode;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MainServer", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = MainServer;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocalServer", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = LocalServer;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocalDBName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = LocalDatabase;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AuditType", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = AuditType;
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", BranchCode);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainServer", MainServer);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocalServer", LocalServer);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocalDBName", LocalDatabase);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // **error on this line**
```

And I'm getting following error on this line:

> Could not find server 'clientname' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name   was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

What to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run distributed queries between two servers. seen must link the two servers.

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   N'Other Server',
   N'SQL Server';
GO
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms190479.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First check the table

```
select * from sys.servers
```

Check if contains the server name "clientname".

If not you need to add linked server to perform the insert operation.This means on your server machine you have to add client server name as linked server.

Or

You can use the C#.net **SqlBulkCopy** method to perform the data transfer easily.